# Contacts sync provider

Tags: android

I create sync provider, everything work, but I can't start my activity when user click to my custom contact data on badge.

contacts.xml:

```
<ContactsSource xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ContactsDataKind android:icon="@drawable/ic_contacts"
    android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.<package>.profile"
    android:summaryColumn="data2"
    android:detailColumn="data3"
    android:detailSocialSummary="true"/>
```

sync_contacts.xml:

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
android:accountType="<package>"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was simple, just add code below to activity

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.<package>.profile"/>
        </intent-filter>
```